# Tag/Untag VLANs from Port Perspective on HP Switch

Tags: hp, vlan, ios

I'm familiar with vlans and tagging, and we usually use the command line interface for our HP Layer 3 switches. I've done quite a few:

```
vlan 10 untagged 21
```

I've always wondered if this was possible to do from the perspective of the port. For example, if I have a port that needs a brand new configuration, it would be amazing to be able to do something like:

```
interface 21 untagged 2 tagged 3 tagged 5
```

and configure the port as needed in one swoop. The command above does not work (even if shorttened to `interface 21 untagged 2`). Is it possible to do port tagging from the perspective of the port rather than the perspective of the vlan? Even just clearing a port would be handy and from hitting `?` at the command line, there appear to be no vlan options within the interface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible to do on an HP switch, where all port membership is configured as part of the vlan configuration.

On the other hand, that is the standard way to do it on a Cisco switch, where a port's config includes all the vlans allowed through it.

Comment: Good to know that Cisco has figured this out! Thanks for the answer!